# How to see changes from commit x to y on github?

Tags: github, diff, commit

I'm trying to see all modifications made from 06e27fd143240e8e4d13b29db831bedece2bf2d3 to the latest e1c34175b5556ac5ce1e60ba56db2493dd9f6b52. I tried

https://github.com/gaganmalvi/kernel_xiaomi_lime/compare/Q:e1c34175b5556ac5ce1e60ba56db2493dd9f6b52%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E...Q:06e27fd143240e8e4d13b29db831bedece2bf2d3

and vice-versa but it does not work.

Also I tried https://github.com/gaganmalvi/kernel_xiaomi_lime/compare/06e27fd143240e8e4d13b29db831bedece2bf2d3%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E...Q which seems to work but brings changes from 2017, but the changes I want to see are from dec 2020 and beyond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compare URL could be something like

```
https://github.com/gaganmalvi/kernel_xiaomi_lime/compare/Q..02ca1a9
```

`Q` is the name of the only branch in that repository. It is used here for the HEAD of the repository.

`02ca1a9` is the "Git Object ID" for the state of the repository after the last commit in Dec 2020.

[GitHub documentation for comparing commits](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/committing-changes-to-your-project/viewing-and-comparing-commits/comparing-commits#comparing-commits)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To compare commits in GitHub, there are two options, sharing the syntax with the `git diff` syntax:

- `A..B` to show the difference between commit A and B (this is equivalent to `diff A B`)
- `A...B` to show the difference between "merge base of A and B" and B (this is indeed equivalent to `diff $(merge-base A B) B`

GitHub URLs:

- Comparing commits directly: https://github.com/gaganmalvi/kernel_xiaomi_lime/compare/06e27fd143240e8e4d13b29db831bedece2bf2d3..e1c34175b5556ac5ce1e60ba56db2493dd9f6b52
- Comparing from merge base: https://github.com/gaganmalvi/kernel_xiaomi_lime/compare/06e27fd143240e8e4d13b29db831bedece2bf2d3...e1c34175b5556ac5ce1e60ba56db2493dd9f6b52

Answer (score 0):

Does

```bash
git diff e1c34175b5556ac5ce1e60ba56db2493dd9f6b52 06e27fd143240e8e4d13b29db831bedece2bf2d3
```

not work?